# Insert object in nested array mongodb nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, nested

So I am trying to insert an object in parameters and have been unsuccessful. My mongodb structure looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "04",
        "name": "test service 4",
        "id": "04",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "title": "testing",
        "description": "test",
        "protocol": "test",
        "operations": [
            {
                "_id": "99",
                "oName": "test op 52222222222",
                "sid": "04",
                "name": "test op 52222222222",
                "oid": "99",
                "parameters": {},
                "description": "testing",
                "returntype": "test"
            },
            {
                "_id": "58",
                "oName": "test op 52222222222",
                "sid": "04",
                "name": "test op 52222222222",
                "oid": "58",
                "parameters": {},
                "description": "testing",
                "returntype": "test"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to be able to add an object into parameters with basic details such as name, id, and type. I am not entirely sure how to tackle this as I have all other CRUD operations implemented up until the parameters part. How should I go about to complete this? I know mongodb has issues when trying to insert something into an array inside an array, so if anyone has any suggestions as to how I can complete this I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

One of the problems is I do not have access to the _id of the root object, but I do have the _id for the operation where I am inserting the parameter. Hence I was trying to insert the parameter using this code:

```
collection.update({"operations":{"$elemMatch": {"oid": oid}}}, {'$addToSet':{"operations.parameters":  {name: "test"} }}, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
        } else {
            res.send(result[0]);
        }
    });
```

This does not work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to complete the insert by using the following code:

```
collection.update({ "operations": {$elemMatch: {_id:oid}}}, {$addToSet: { "operations.$.parameters" : parameter}}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
        } else {
            res.send(result[0]);
        }
});
```

Just in case anyone needed it.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you need to use [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array), The example I am copying from the link is almost the same as in your case:

```
db.students.update(
   { _id: 4, "grades.grade": 85 },
   { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 6 } }
)
```

Comment: the problem is this is being done with a post call in a nodejs api, and in this case I do not have access to _id 04, that is the reason I do the $elemMatch, mine is also an array inside an array (parameters inside operations). I have tried this example by hard-coding the initial _id and it still does not work

Comment: You have the `_id` of the operation. Is that unique across the collection? If so, you can use `$` and match on the condition `operations._id : <your _id>`, very similar to the sample above. If not, your update is poorly defined. Do you want to update one operation with the given `_id`? Which one? Do you care? Do you want to update all of them with the given `_id`?